# Trying to find fantasy book about a great walled city holding off huge army

Tags: story-identification, novel

The story takes place in an ancient city with many walls protecting it. It was once prosperous and full of people but has since lost its prominence. A huge army (over 100,000 strong) is coming to attack down from the north. A man, maybe a general in the old city, is forced to defend it as best he can with no where near enough men.

They put up such a good defence that the invading army decides to bypass the city out of respect and continues south to conquer other lands.

I read this book in the 90's but not sure when it was published.

Comment: If mine was the correct answer, don't forget to click the "accept" button to show it.

Answer (score 10):

This sounds a lot like [Legend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legend_(Gemmell_novel)) by David Gemmell (published in 1984).

> The novel follows the stories of two men who find their destiny at
>   Dros Delnoch. Regnak Wanderer (Rek for short) an ex-army officer and
>   natural 'baresark', seeing a war brewing, resigned his commission
>   because he lacked the courage to risk his life and took to a life of
>   wandering. Rek is an idealist and eventually he returns to Delnoch at
>   the persuasion of the woman he falls in love with and finds his
>   destiny as the Earl of Bronze. **The other man is the greatest hero of
>   the Drenai people - Druss the Legend. His death was foretold defending
>   Delnoch and while given the choice to avoid it and fall into senility
>   Druss (and his once possessed axe Snaga) marched to the great fortress
>   to defend his people one last time. In this story Druss is in his
>   sixties and much weaker than his prime but still a formidable warrior
>   and an inspirational leader to the Drenai.** The story also flicks into
>   the perspective of several defenders during different stages of the
>   siege as time goes on. It also follows The Thirty, a group of 30
>   warrior priests of the light whose purpose is to fight and die (except
>   for one priest that leaves to continue the order at the end of each
>   great battle) for the greater good and their people, the Drenai.

Comment: I immediately thought of Legend as well